# c# Windows Phone 8.1 Install Twitterizer using Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I need to allow a user to login using his Twitter Details and if he's a valid Twitter user then show his Tweets to him. For this I want to use Twitterizer but am unable to find a command to install it using Package Manager Console.

Can someone give the command to install Twitterizer using Package Manager Console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:
Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json (Should update you to the latest)

then try

Install-Package twitterizer -Version 2.4.2 -IgnoreDependencies

Then add the assembly packages\twitterizer.2.4.2\lib\net40-Client\Twitterizer2.dll
via add assembly.

I would test and make sure though it still works because the dependency was specific to Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.5.  So use at your own risk. :)

Comment: `Install-Package : Could not install package 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.5'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package twitterizer -Version 2.4.2`

Comment: It looks like you can install the latest Newtonsoft.Json then try again.

Comment: `Install-Package : Already referencing a newer version of 'Newtonsoft.Json'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package twitterizer -Version 2.4.2
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand`